# put html checkbox value into text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox with a value of `U`

i want to put this value into a text input when the checkbox is checked.

how can i do this using javascript or jquery? I need to be able to do it on multiple checkboxes and input text fields too

Comment: There are a lot of ways of doing this, however it would entire depend on how you page is structured. Please post your HTML and any JS code you have already tried.

Comment: You need to provide more information, like things you've tried, what code you have so far, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="U" id="checkBox"/>

<input type="text" value="" id="textInput" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#checkBox").change(function(){

    $("#textInput").val($(this).val());

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fsjcd/)

Comment: can you make it so when the box is uncheck it will remove the checkbox value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="U" />Check</label>
<input type="text" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function(){
   var is_checked=$(this).prop('checked');
   var val='';
   if(is_checked)
     val=this.value;
   $('input[type="text"]').val(val);
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/v65QS/)

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest way to do this :o)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                var checkboxInput = document.getElementById('checkboxInput'),
                    textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');

                checkboxInput.addEventListener('click', UpdateTextInput, false);
            };

            function UpdateTextInput () {
                if(checkboxInput.checked) {
                    textInput.value = checkboxInput.value;
                }
                else {
                    textInput.value = '';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxInput" value="U"/>
        <input type="text" id="textInput" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one textbox is associated with every checkbox like below.

**HTML Pattern :**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="test1" id="test1" checked><label>Test</label>
<input type="text" class="text1"id="textbox1" name="textbox1" value="">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var vals = $(this).val();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).next().next("input[type='text']").val(vals);
    }else{
        $(this).next().next("input[type='text']").val("");
    }

});
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/uH4us/

Comment: perfect! is this possible without having the <label> on the checkboxes? i have tried removing it and it stops working

Comment: @charlie: Yeah, it's possible. Use  `$(this).next("input[type='text']").val(vals);`Here is the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uH4us/